# Reactjs: Routing from a Navbar with Array

Tags: reactjs, routes, navbar

I'm actually learning react and faced a problem, I don´t really know how to handle. I got a Navigation Component which creates a Navbar. It was a OnePage before and I had no problems to navigate though my page, but now I want to create more pages.

My actuall Navigation.js looke like this:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Portfolio from "../portfolio";
import About from "../../components/About";
import Skills from "../../components/Skills";
import Projects from "../../components/Projects";
import Resume from "../../components/Resume/";
import Contant from "../../components/Contact";

import NotFoundPage from "../404";
import "./style.scss";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Portfolio} />
        <Route path="/home" exact component={Portfolio} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/skills" exact component={Skills} />
        <Route path="/Projects" exact component={Projects} />
        <Route path="/Resume" exact component={Resume} />
        <Route path="/Contact" exact component={Contant} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Porfolio from "../portfolio";
import Projects from "../../components/Projects/index"

import NotFoundPage from "../404";
import "./style.scss";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Porfolio} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

What I want to archive now is to actually got to page /about when I hit my About entry on my page.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your app another list menu

`menu=[{url:"/home",component:Home},{url:"/about",component:About}];`

and update your Switch

```
`<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact componenenter code heret={Porfolio} />
    {menu.map((temp,index)=>
        <Route key={index} url={temp.url} component={temp.component}/>
    )}
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it looks like you have your navigation page set up properly with all your routes working correctly. The next step is in your NavBar where you have all your links to the pages. you'll need to `import { Link } from "react-router-dom"` and then use the link component

`<Link to={'/about'}>About</Link>`

This should change the route in your address bar to localhost:3000/about

you can check out the Link component more here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

The one thing I don't see is the Router in your App component which needs to wrap the other pieces, it may just be higher up the chain in your code

```
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Routes .../>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

and the last thing I might look at is that both the navigation and App are exporting App, it might be a good idea to change one of those

Comment: I tried this out, but now I get the message : "target element not found"

Comment: My appologies, I realize you are using react-scroll, and I was thinking you were using react router. To Clarify, you want to have the user see the content on a new page instead of scrolling down to the content?

Comment: No Problem m8 :) . Yeah, I don´t want a big "One Page" anymore and want to split my components on Single Pages. I updated my Navigation on the top

Comment: I've updated my answer in case you're still working on it